# Angular: Is there a way to stop a component from initializing it's view?

Tags: angular

What I am trying to do is, if this.pageService.getForbidden() return true.

I don't want this component to load or initialized, is there a way to achieve this?

```
export class ViewRComponent extends ViewRulesParentComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

    constructor( protected readonly pageService: PageService,
               ) {
        if( this.pageService.getForbidden()){
        // this.pageService.getForbidden() is true, I don't want this component to load 
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you got a parent component you can just use a `<div>` with `*ngIf=pageService.getForbidden()`

something like this:

parent.html

```
<div *ngIf=pageService.getForbidden()>
  <view-r-component></view-r-component>
</div>
```

where `<view-r-component>` its your ViewRComponent component

i hope it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your application is structured, but you can use Angular Guards to prevent the component to be loaded, something like CanActivate and CanLoad guards can help you.

https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate

https://angular.io/api/router/CanLoad

Comment: How can I do it without using angular router?